# Right margin/padding in Beamer columns environment is wrong

Tags: beamer, columns, beamerposter

I'm trying to make a poster in Beamer. The padding for multiple-column environments is wrong: the left side of the multiple columns is correctly aligned, but the right side adds extra padding. See below:

[image]

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7442/margins-in-beamer-columns) may be related, but the solution doesn't seem to do anything useful in this case. I've also [looked at this solution](http://www.ojdo.de/wp/2015/03/how-to-horizontally-align-beamer-columns-with-surrounding-text/) to no avail. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74808/how-to-line-up-blocks-in-columns-with-full-width-blocks-in-beamer-beamerposter?rq=1) seems related, and gets partway to an answer, but doesn't explain the spurious right margin. It's not an issue with right-padding inside blocks, as the problem occurs even if the columns are simply introduced into the `frame` environment.

Here is a reduced example

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
% Set up as beamerposter
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=A4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{Singapore4}

% Enable T1 (more modern) fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\title[]{Title}
\author[]{Authors}
\date{}
\institute[]{Institute} 

\begin{document}

\setlength\columnsep{0pt}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{block}{}
I've placed hrules in the columns to show that the spacing error comes from the column environment and not the block environment.\\
\hrulefill
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\vspace{5em}\end{block}\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\end{block}\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}

The problem is not related to Beamer blocks as "naked" columns show the same issue:\\
\hrulefill
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\end{block}\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\end{block}\end{column}
\end{columns}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And here is the source code for my style file

```
% Copyright 2007 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm


%\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /Users/joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeSingapore.sty,v d02a7cf4d8ae 2010/06/17 09:11:41 rivanvx $
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\AtBeginDocument{%
  {
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
  } 
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {%
    color(0cm)=(bg);
    color(1.25cm)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
  }
  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}
\beamertemplatedotitem
\mode
<all>

% Template from T has special colors
\definecolor{TYellow}{RGB}{234,230, 99}
\definecolor{TBlue}{RGB}{ 29, 23, 96}
\definecolor{TAzure}{RGB}{151,147,204}
\definecolor{TWhite}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{TPale}{RGB}{232,229,177}
\definecolor{VABlue}{RGB}{25,73,128}
\definecolor{RUST}{HTML}{EB7A59}
\definecolor{AZURE}{HTML}{5AA0DF}
\definecolor{OCHRE}{HTML}{EEA300}
\definecolor{TURQUOISE}{HTML}{00BAC9}
\definecolor{BLACK}{HTML}{44525C}
\definecolor{WHITE}{HTML}{F1F0E9}

% Configure the colors for the headline
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=OCHRE}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=OCHRE}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}
\setbeamercolor{date in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}
\setbeamercolor{logobox}{bg=BLACK}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=white,fg=VABlue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=WHITE,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}

% define a new register to hold an intermediate size calculation 
% that we'll use in defining the headline
\newlength{\residual}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode

  \setlength{\residual}{\paperwidth-20cm}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \begin{columns}[c]
      \begin{column}{1cm}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}[b]{9cm}
      %{\large\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in headline}\href{mrule@staffmail.ed.ac.uk}{mrule@staffmail.ed.ac.uk}}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}{\residual}
        \vskip1cm
        \centering
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{
            \color{fg}{\Huge\selectfont {\inserttitle}}\\[3ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{
            \color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{
            \color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}  
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}[t]{9cm}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}{1cm}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vskip2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% Alignment grid
%\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]

% no navigation on a poster
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  

% Make the figure caption labels bold
%\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\bfseries}
% Beamer disables figure numbering by default (it assumes figure numbers on 
% slides would not make sense). This command restores autonubering
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[period]

\setbeamerfont*{block title}{family=\sffamily,series=\bfseries,size=\large}
```

The desired behavior is that the left and right margins of a multiple-column environment should be identical. Any thoughts?

---

A more minimal MWE - Observe what happens when `\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray,fg=black}` is removed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray,fg=black}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

    \hrulefill

    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \hrulefill
            \begin{block}{test}
                test
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \hrulefill
            \begin{block}{test}
                test
            \end{block}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

    \vskip1cm
    \hrulefill  
    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \hrulefill
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            \hrulefill
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Workaround: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131881/36296

Comment: Explanation: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103974/36296

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the problem! Although it appears related to a well-known bug in Beamer (can we patch this? is there a better forum for reporting bugs?), I wasn't able to find the solution for the specific defect I noticed (right margin), so I think I'll leave the question up even though it is slightly redundant, if it can help route searches toward a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried the workrounds I linked in the first comment? I tried the "Redefinition of block-environment" with your theme and get all your blocks aligned on the right margin.

Comment: Yes, I just tried your solution and the workaround works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
%% Set up as beamerposter
%\usepackage{grffile}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
%\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm


%\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /Users/joseph/Documents/LaTeX/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeSingapore.sty,v d02a7cf4d8ae 2010/06/17 09:11:41 rivanvx $
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\mode<presentation>
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\AtBeginDocument{%
  {
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
  } 
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {%
    color(0cm)=(bg);
    color(1.25cm)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
  }
  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}
\beamertemplatedotitem
\mode
<all>

% Template from T has special colors
\definecolor{TYellow}{RGB}{234,230, 99}
\definecolor{TBlue}{RGB}{ 29, 23, 96}
\definecolor{TAzure}{RGB}{151,147,204}
\definecolor{TWhite}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{TPale}{RGB}{232,229,177}
\definecolor{VABlue}{RGB}{25,73,128}
\definecolor{RUST}{HTML}{EB7A59}
\definecolor{AZURE}{HTML}{5AA0DF}
\definecolor{OCHRE}{HTML}{EEA300}
\definecolor{TURQUOISE}{HTML}{00BAC9}
\definecolor{BLACK}{HTML}{44525C}
\definecolor{WHITE}{HTML}{F1F0E9}

% Configure the colors for the headline
\setbeamercolor{headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=OCHRE}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=OCHRE}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}
\setbeamercolor{date in headline}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}
\setbeamercolor{logobox}{bg=BLACK}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=white,fg=VABlue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=WHITE,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=BLACK,fg=TWhite}

% define a new register to hold an intermediate size calculation 
% that we'll use in defining the headline
\newlength{\residual}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode

  \setlength{\residual}{\paperwidth-20cm}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \begin{columns}[c]
      \begin{column}{1cm}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}[b]{9cm}
      %{\large\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in headline}\href{mrule@staffmail.ed.ac.uk}{mrule@staffmail.ed.ac.uk}}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}{\residual}
        \vskip1cm
        \centering
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{
            \color{fg}{\Huge\selectfont {\inserttitle}}\\[3ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{
            \color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{
            \color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}  
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}[t]{9cm}
      \end{column}

      \begin{column}{1cm}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vskip2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

% Alignment grid
%\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]

% no navigation on a poster
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  

% Make the figure caption labels bold
%\setbeamerfont{caption}{series=\bfseries}
% Beamer disables figure numbering by default (it assumes figure numbers on 
% slides would not make sense). This command restores autonubering
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}[period]

\setbeamerfont*{block title}{family=\sffamily,series=\bfseries,size=\large}

% Enable T1 (more modern) fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}

\title[]{Title}
\author[]{Authors}
\date{}
\institute[]{Institute} 

\newsavebox{\squaredblocktext}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
    \par\vskip\medskipamount%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
            \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
        \end{beamercolorbox}}%
        \begin{lrbox}{\squaredblocktext}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
                \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{block end}{
            \end{minipage}%
        \end{lrbox}%
        {\parskip0pt\par}%
        \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}{}
        {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
        \usebeamerfont{block body}%
        \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5ex\relax][l]{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
            \usebox{\squaredblocktext}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }\vskip\smallskipamount%
}


\begin{document}

\setlength\columnsep{0pt}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{block}{}
I've placed hrules in the columns to show that the spacing error comes from the column environment and not the block environment.\\
\hrulefill
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\vspace{5em}\end{block}\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\end{block}\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{block}

The problem is not related to Beamer blocks as "naked" columns show the same issue:\\
\hrulefill
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\end{block}\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth-.5cm}\hrulefill\begin{block}{}\end{block}\end{column}
\end{columns}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]