# beamer: Block Environment in Combination With Column Environment

Tags: beamer

I want to use the `block` environment together with the `column` environment in a `beamer` document.

> The margin/spacing is getting wrong/ugly in this combination. I want
>   that the blocks are exactly as wide as a normal text would occupy (so
>   that the `text margin`s are still correct).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=5mm}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\begin{document}

% Frame 1 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{No Column Environment}
    \begin{block}{Block Title}
    Block Text.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

% Frame 2 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Column Environment -- Only Left Block Environment}

\begin{columns}
    \column{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Block Text.
        \end{block}
    \column{.50\textwidth}
        \color{blue}\vrule width\textwidth height\textwidth
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

% Frame 3 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Column Environment -- Left and Right Block Environment}

\begin{columns}
    \column{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Block Text.
        \end{block}
    \column{.50\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Block Text.
        \end{block} 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

% Frame 4 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Column Environment Only}

\begin{columns}
    \column{.50\textwidth}
        \color{blue}\vrule width\textwidth height\textwidth
    \column{.50\textwidth}
        \color{blue}\vrule width\textwidth height\textwidth
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason for the yellow background is, so that it is clear where the page has its borders.

Trying the idea from [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) in one of the comments leads to.

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth] 
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Block Title} Block Text. 
        \end{block}%
        \end{column} \hfill%
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth} 
        \begin{block}{Block Title} Block Text. 
        \end{block} 
        \end{column} 
    \end{columns}
    \begin{block}{Block Title}
    Block Text.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

---

### Bug?! I Opened an Issue on GitHub

- I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/381
- **Update [2020-02-17]:** The issue was **closed** on 22 Aug 2017 :).

---

### Similar or Duplicate or Related

- [Beamer: Default blocks in and out the columns environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/)
- [How to center blocks and columns in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59974).

Answer (score 5):

Setting the width of the columns environment to fixed value will solve your issue. You can do so i.e. using the option `[onlytextwidth]`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=5mm}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=gray}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow}

\begin{document}

% Frame 1 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{No Column Environment}
    \begin{block}{Block Title}
    Block Text.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

% Frame 2 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Column Environment -- Only Left Block Environment}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \column{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Block Text.
        \end{block}
    \column{.47\textwidth}
        Right Column Text.
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

% Frame 3 -----------------------
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Column Environment -- Left and Right Block Environment}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \column{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Block Text.
        \end{block}
    \column{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Block Title}
        Block Text.
        \end{block}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(You have to do some fine tuning of the widths of the actual columns)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that I do not have to do fine tuning. The right border is still "dancing".

Comment: Well, I set the column width to `.47\textwidth` so that there is a gap. Maybe the manual will help you figure out the correct (not ad hock dreamt up) values . . .

Comment: the boarder problem with `onlyextwidth` is an old problem of the rectangular blocks, does not happen with rounded blocks. I think we already had this questions somewhere... I'm going to search

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the info. I tried to search the problem before -- if you find the answer/question that you mention, then please let me know

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner My first answer ever on this site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131881/36296, see especially my third approach.

Comment: @samcarter I tried the code in the comment -- see updated answer. Still not a good solution -- assuming I did it right.

Comment: @samcarter you are right: with rounded blocks (i.e. `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]`) it doesn't jump.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry for the confusion with the comment, still had the rounded them in my code from testing...have deleted it now. But the redefinition from the linked answer should work

Comment: @samcarter Could this be considered a bug in beamer?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Ask the maintainer.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Is your original question a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131879/beamer-default-blocks-in-and-out-the-columns-environment or not? Looks a lot like it to me.

Comment: @DG' Looks pretty similar -- thanks for pointing ist out. I just opened a issue on GitHub. I'll wait if there is a response. If not then I will delete my question if the community thinks so.

Comment: @DG' Sorry for chatting in your comments, you must have had a ton of pings :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner no need to delete anything