# How to center all blocks within beamer automatically?

Tags: beamer, block

I found a [nice solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-beamer) to change the width of the blocks within my beamer document.

The blocks themselves are aligned left. Is there any opportunity to automatically center each block without putting them into a `\begin{center}<block>\end{center}` or something like that?

Here is my MWE and how it looks like at the moment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}%
}{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] 
            $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103974/187753) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}{\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\linewidth}, center, , frame}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{block}{\end{adjustbox}}
```

The frame is just to let you see what happens. The commands will place the block in a minipage then center it. The white space above the block means that the block environment automatically inserts an empty space above itself.

Full code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
    \centering%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}%
}{}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}{\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\linewidth}, center, frame}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{block}{\end{adjustbox}}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

        \begin{theorem}[Pythagoras] 
            $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
        \end{theorem}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```